# Wrong Month interpreted in Jquery Date picker, data being pulled from MySQL

Tags: jquery, mysql, jquery-ui, datepicker

thanks for helping in advance. I am just starting out so I may be doing this entirely the wrong way

OK the problem is that the date value **2012, 2, 13** (2012 Feb 13) in PHP when called in the DatePicker is interpreted as 2012 March 13 because 2 means the third month when starting form 0 is March, I got that much.

```
//Getting the Min Date from the Datetime field

    $sqlmin = "Select min(datetime) from table1";
    $resultmin = mysql_query($sqlmin);
    $mindate = mysql_fetch_array($resultmin);
    $datetime1 = date('Y, n, j', strtotime($mindate[0])); //this will give me 2012, 2, 13 (Feb)
```

Now in the JS part

```
    $(function() {
       $( "#fromdate" ).datepicker({
       dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
       minDate: new Date( php echo $datetime1; ),  // this thinks it is March but i want Feb
```

So the question is how can I get the month to be **Feb** instead of **March** in the Datepicker?

Comment: I thought about that but how do i subtract only the MONTH by 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this format instead: `"F j, Y, g:i a"`

Refs.:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php#example-665

```
$datetime1 = date("F j, Y, g:i a"); // March 10, 2001, 5:16 pm
```

That is one of the JavaScript expected formats.

```
minDate: new Date("<?php echo $datetime1; ?>")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the new Date function:

```
minDate: 
$(function() {
   var phpDate = new Date( php echo $datetime1; );
   $( "#fromdate" ).datepicker({
   dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
   minDate: phpDate.setMonth(phpDate.getMonth() - 1),
```

getMonth will return 0-11, and setMonth will use that correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the "wrong month" thing by creating a list of month names:

```
$(function() {
                $( "#alkupvm" ).datepicker({
                    dateFormat:"yy-mm-dd", 
                    firstDay:1, 
                    dayNamesMin:["Su","Ma","Ti","Ke","To","Pe","La"],
                    monthNames:["Tammikuu", "Helmikuu", "Maaliskuu", "Huhtikuu", "Toukokuu", "Kes&auml;kuu", "Hein&auml;kuu", "Elokuu", "Syyskuu", "Lokakuu", "Marraskuu", "Joulukuu"],
                    minDate:"-2y",
                    stepMonths: 1,
                    maxDate:"+2m"

                    });
                });
```

Here specifically the monthNames list/array. Now the month shows up correctly.